# Converting from int to wide character string using sprintf_s

Tags: c, string, windows, widestring

My goal is to convert an `int` to a wide character string and prefix it with another wide string. My current solution is this:

```
#define bufsize 20
char buffer[bufsize];
sprintf_s(buffer,bufsize,"%s%d", "my prefix", 42);
wchar_t wbuffer[bufsize];
mbstowcs_s(NULL, wbuffer, buffer, bufsize);
```

I incorrectly expected that the following would work:

```
#define bufsize 20
wchar_t buffer[bufsize];
swprintf_s(buffer,bufsize,"%s%d",L"my prefix",  42);
```

Is there a more succinct version of my solution that works? It seems wrong that I have to do the `int` to `char[]` conversion and then convert to `wchar_t[]`. Why can't I just convert from `int` to `wchar_t*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the L prefix for the *format string*

```
swprintf_s(buffer, bufsize, L"%s%d", L"my prefix",  42);
```

The parameters can however be normal string, but you need to use [`%S` in MSVC and `%ls` in standard C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019)

```
swprintf_s(buffer, bufsize, L"%S%d", "my prefix",  42);
```

Note that macros typically have ALL_CAPS names to differentiate them from variables